# C# RegExp с "-" для чистки текста

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Исходный регэксп

```
@"(?!\s)(?!\d*\-\w*)(?!\w*\-\d*)(\b[^\d#]+\b)"
```

Данные на входе

```
test тест tЭst 
4rtiku1 Artikul \t     46436345634
600D Kit 18-55mm IS II
@test@
#####Am42
757#761###
Slit Pointy-Toe Flats
Pointy-55
ёканыйбабай68
ёканыйбабай-68
cm18-55
ee-55
55-ee
```

Хочу получить

```
4rtiku1 46436345634
600D 18-55mm
#####Am42
757#761###
Pointy-55
ёканыйбабай68
ёканыйбабай-68
cm18-55
ee-55
55-ee
```

Но получается

```
4rtiku1 46436345634
600D 18-55mm @
#####Am42
757#761###
55
ёканыйбабай68
ёканыйбабай-68
cm18-55
ee-55
55-
```

Как поправить регэксп чтобы [[@test](/users/1155/test)](/users/1155/test)@ вырезать полностью, а text-num не резался пополам?

Answer (score 1):

Делаю не с помощью поиска, а с помощью замены. Может быть коряво, но работает:

```
text = @"test тест tЭst ....";
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<!\d+|\d-|#)(?<=^| )[@A-Za-zА-Яа-я\\-]+(?!\w+|-\d+|#)");
//Удаляем лишние пробелы
text = Regex.Replace(text, " +", " ");
```

Ход мыслей: мы удаляем буквенно-знаковое выражение без цифр (как я понял)[[[@A](/users/967/aghasalim)](/users/967/aghasalim)-Za-zА-Яа-я\-](буквы, цифры, собаки, \ и -)
Перед этим выражением соответственно не должно быть цифр, цифр с тире и решеток(?<!\d+|\d-|#)
И это удаляемое слово слева ограничивается либо пробелом, либо началом строки (?<=^| )
Справа оно также не должно содержать решеток, цифр и цифр с тире (?!\w+|-\d+|#)

Comment: Моё решение

var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=\A|[\s\t])([^\d#]+|\S{1,3})(?>[\s\t]|\Z)", " ");
result = string.Join(" ", result.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
return result;